# Java3D: Determining when an object is out of field of view

Tags: java-3d

I've Googled and search Stackoverflow but I can't seem to find the answer:

How do I determine when an 3D object/shape is completely out of the field of view?  E.g. I have an object moving along the x axis, eventually it will move out of view.

Best regards,
TX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure that you're looking for [viewing frustum culling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_surface_determination#Viewing_frustum_culling). Please don't use the tag "java-3d" if you don't use Java 3D 1.6.0.

Comment: I'll investigate it further, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.